# detached entity passed to persist while using spring jpa with @mapsId

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have two entities User and UserPersonalDetails with OneToOne mapping. Below are my classes

***User class***

```
@Entity
@Table
public class User implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    Long userId;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    String firstName;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    String lastName;


    @Column(nullable = false,unique=true)
    String email;

    @Column
    String mobile;

    @Column(nullable = true)
    String password;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    String role;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    boolean isAccountLocked;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    boolean isAccountDisabled;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    boolean isPasswordExipred;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    boolean isAccountExipred;

    public User() {}

public User(long userId, String email, String role) {
    this.userId = userId;
    this.email = email;
    this.role = role;
}
```

***UserPersonalDetails class***

```
@Entity
@Table
public class UserPersonalDetails {

    @Id
    Long userId;

    @JoinColumn(name = "userId")
    @OneToOne( cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @MapsId

    User user;

    Long univercityId;
    Long collageId;
    String address;
    String parentContact;
    String tempAddress;
```

When I tried to saving the UserPersonalDetails object with spring jpa's *JpaRepository* it end up with below error

> nested exception is
>   org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached
>   entity passed to persist: com.asset.app.user.User; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to
>   persist: com.asset.app.user.User]

Note : I don't want to save/update the User object again while saving/updating UserPersonalDetails object in DB